# AngularJS multiple submit button repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

i'm working on AngularJS

I have this problem:

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS63P.jpg)

In HTML i used this code for show submit button for two type of form.

One for TEXT Form and one for ENUM Form:

```
<div ng-controller="githubController3">
                <div ng-repeat="x in names | limitTo:1">
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        <h3>{{ x.name }}</h3></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="githubController3">
                <div ng-controller="githubControllerForm1">
                    <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction">
                        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                            {{ x.name }}*

                            <form ng-submit="submitForm()">

                                <a ng-if="x.id=='name'">
                                    <input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="formData.properties[0].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ name }} </input>
                                </a>

                                <a ng-if="x.id=='email'">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.properties[1].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ email }} </input>
                                </a>

                                <br>

                                <a ng-if="x.type=='long'">
                                    <input type="number" name="numero" ng-model="formData.properties[2].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ income }} </input>
                                </a>


                                <br>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
                                </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--NEL CASO DI ENUM PRESENTA QUESTO FORM-->

            <div ng-controller="githubController3">
                <div ng-controller="githubControllerForm1">
                    <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction2">
                        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                            {{ x.name }}*

                            <form ng-submit="submitForm2()">
                                <a ng-if="x.type=='enum'">
                                    <select ng-model="formData2.properties[0].value" ng-options="y.id as y.name for y in x.enumValues "></select>
                                </a>
                                <br>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit Enum!
                                </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    </form>
```

How I can show only one submit button instead of multiple repetition of it ?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in this line you write submit form inside `ng-repeat`. It will repeat how much data in names array.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
```

Remove `ng-repeat` then it show only one submit button